# How to remember position in official mac twitter client?

Tags: macos, twitter

I read twitter often on my mac and using official client for OSX. After relaunch client I will see not that place where I were before quit. But it's awful :( Does anyone know how I can do that?

I know that TweetBot can do that, but clients for iPhone and iPad could do it, why client for mac can't or how to set it up for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the OSX client just can't do that. Although you could just leave it open and it should have the same effect.

It might also be worth pointing out that support for the official Twitter client for OSX has been/will be dropped, so now would be a good time to look for an alternative. See this: http://isource.com/2012/09/07/twitter-in-turmoil-report-claims-twitter-to-drop-support-for-official-mac-client/